# Expo React Native App crashing on real ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo

my ios app installed on real device but it crached immediately ,
I did not use any library or somthing else ,
I run my app on
simulator ,
emulator ,
and real android device
and every thing is ok.
but in real ios device not work.

this is my log when running app :
............................................................................................

```
default 00:52:43.951395-0800 SpringBoard SBIconView touches began with event: <UITouchesEvent: 0x2830fcb40> timestamp: 2010.75 touches: {(

   <UITouch: 0x104a0dd80> phase: Began tap count: 1 force: 0.000 window: <SBHomeScreenWindow: 0x115c61f20; HomeScreen-0x115c61f20-6; baseClass = UIWindow; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280a6d9e0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x280a6d890>> view: <SBIconView: 0x105977200; frame: {{201, 470}, {60, 74}}; icon: <SBApplicationIcon: 0x282b5e400; nodeID: [`My Bundle Id`]; bundleID: [`My Bundle Id`]>; location: SBIconLocationRoot; isTouchDownInIcon: YES> location in window: {245, 498} previous location in window: {245, 498} location in view: {44, 28} previous location in view: {44, 28}

)}, tap gesture: <SBIconTapGestureRecognizer: 0x109b65680; baseClass = UITapGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; view = <SBIconView 0x105977200>; target= <(action=tapGestureDidChange:, target=<SBIconView 0x105977200>)>>

default 00:52:44.104943-0800 SpringBoard Asked to bootstrap a new process with identity: application<[`My Bundle Id`]>

default 00:52:44.105154-0800 SpringBoard Creating process (sync=true) with identity: application<[`My Bundle Id`]>

default 00:52:44.105710-0800 SpringBoard Created <FBWorkspace: 0x2832eb2e0; application<[`My Bundle Id`]>>

default 00:52:44.105818-0800 SpringBoard Bootstrapping application<[`My Bundle Id`]> with intent foreground-interactive

default 00:52:44.108865-0800 runningboardd Acquiring assertion targeting application<[`My Bundle Id`]> from originator [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:63] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "FBApplicationProcess" ID:32-63-698 target:application<[`My Bundle Id`]> attributes:[

<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.frontboard" name:"Bootstrap-Foreground" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">,

<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.frontboard" name:"Visibility" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">

]>

default 00:52:44.108967-0800 runningboardd Assertion 32-63-698 (target:application<[`My Bundle Id`]>) will be created as active

default 00:52:44.109011-0800 runningboardd Executing launch request for application<[`My Bundle Id`]> (FBApplicationProcess)

default 00:52:44.109468-0800 runningboardd Creating and launching job for: application<[`My Bundle Id`]>

default 00:52:44.109518-0800 runningboardd _mutateContextIfNeeded called for [`My Bundle Id`]

default 00:52:44.123935-0800 SpringBoard [Main] dispatch event:

<SBTransitionSwitcherModifierEvent: 0x2839e2600; type: MainTransition; transitionID: B7D36934-ABF4-4DE0-8F4D-8C45B11E320E; phase: Prepare; animated: YES; fromAppLayout: 0x0; toAppLayout: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>; fromEnvironmentMode: home-screen; toEnvironmentMode: application; pendingTermination: {(

)}; activating: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>; dosidoTransitionDirection: 0>

default 00:52:44.124492-0800 SpringBoard [Main] handle response:

<SBSwitcherModifierEventResponse: 0x2808b49f0> {

   <SBSwitcherModifierEventResponse: 0x2808b7de0> {

    <SBTimerEventSwitcherEventResponse: 0x2808b7630; delay: 0.300000; reason: kSBTransitionModifierInvalidateAsyncRenderingReason>;

    <SBInvalidateAdjustedAppLayoutsSwitcherEventResponse: 0x2808b6850>;

};

   <SBSwitcherModifierEventResponse: 0x2808b4930> {

    <SBUpdateLayoutSwitcherEventResponse: 0x281f2aec0; updateVisibleItems; layout; style; mode: None>;

    <SBRequestFolderSnapshotsSwitcherEventResponse: 0x2808b6d30; snapshotRequested: YES>;

    <SBIconOverlayVisibilitySwitcherEventResponse: 0x281f2a000; visible: YES; appLayout: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>>;

    <SBIconViewVisibilitySwitcherEventResponse: 0x28262a5d0; visible: NO; animationSettings: 0x0; appLayout: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>>;

    <SBTimerEventSwitcherEventResponse: 0x2808b7d50; delay: 0.300

default 00:52:44.136853-0800 SpringBoard [Main] dispatch event:

<SBTransitionSwitcherModifierEvent: 0x283989800; type: MainTransition; transitionID: B7D36934-ABF4-4DE0-8F4D-8C45B11E320E; phase: Animate; animated: YES; fromAppLayout: 0x0; toAppLayout: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>; fromEnvironmentMode: home-screen; toEnvironmentMode: application; pendingTermination: {(

)}; activating: <SBAppLayout: 0x2810b6ac0; primary: [`My Bundle Id`]:default; environment: main>; dosidoTransitionDirection: 0>

default 00:52:44.139816-0800 SpringBoard Asked to bootstrap a new process with identity: application<[`My Bundle Id`]>

default 00:52:44.139880-0800 SpringBoard A pending process already exists with this identity: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x12002c1b0; application<[`My Bundle Id`]>:<invalid>>

default 00:52:44.181411-0800 runningboardd Invalidating assertion 32-63-698 (target:application<[`My Bundle Id`]>) from originator [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:63]

error 00:52:44.181569-0800 SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x12002c1b0; application<[`My Bundle Id`]>:<invalid>> with error: <NSError: 0x280969e60; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "Launch failed."> {

   NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x280969b90; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 88>;

}
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664863) might help.

Comment: I think problem is with your  bundle id , Open XCode and change your bundle id, like com.MyBundleId to learn more about bundle id check this https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers/